# System.load() method not loading shared libraries whithout setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, environment-variables

I'm facing a strange issue while loading shared libraries in Linux. There are two Shared libraries (suppose abc.so and xyz.so) in my application. abc.so is dependent on xyz.so i.e. whenever you will try to load abc.so jvm will first load xyz.so.

Now, when I'm loading these libraries by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the folder containing these two libraries, its working without any problem. However, When I'm trying to load abc.so with System.load("%FULL_PATH%/abc.so") its not getting loaded. Following line is displayed as the error:
undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual.

Can any one help me in understanding this error? Thanks in advance!

Note: Due to some project requirement I can not change LD_LIBRARY_PATH and therefore I need to load abc.so by using System.load() method.

Answer (score 0):

The load is failing because the linker cannot resolve the 'xyz.so' dependency on 'abc.so'. The Linux loader does not automatically look for 'xyz.so' in the same directory as 'abc.so'. You need to explicitly tell it where to look either via the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable or by modifying the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file.

I haven't tried it from within Java but in Python modules when I need to load DLLs I usually just modify the process's environment variable immediately before attempting to load the library. It's a lot easier than writing a wrapper script or modifying your home directory's dot files.

Alternatively, you could also just manually load all of the prerequisites in the proper order. However, you'd need to ensure that the loader placed all of the symbols in the global symbol table rather than loading them privately. Not sure how Java handles that.